# Mysql query with multiple status variation related to pagination

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
id  |  eventid   |  category  | type
----+------------+------------+------
1   |      1     |  music     | event
2   |      2     |  music     | event
3   |      3     |  music     | event
4   |      4     |  music     | event
5   |      5     |  music     | page
6   |      6     |  music     | page
```

Now i need to fetch the data of 4 records in which 2 from the table with status event and 2 from the table with status page

Example:

```
id  |  eventid   |  category  | type
----+------------+------------+------
1   |      1     |  music     | event
2   |      2     |  music     | event

5   |      5     |  music     | page
6   |      6     |  music     | page
```

I have tried with below query but i am getting error

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_subcategory
WHERE category =  'music'
AND TYPE =  'event'
LIMIT 2 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM event_subcategory
WHERE TYPE =  'page'
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `LIMIT` in a `UNION`, it's a good idea to use parenthesis around your subqueries so you're sure to limit the correct select, without them, the second `LIMIT` applies to both subselects. This works more like I think you want it to;

```
(SELECT * FROM event_subcategory WHERE category = 'music' AND TYPE = 'event' LIMIT 2)
UNION     
(SELECT * FROM event_subcategory WHERE TYPE = 'page' LIMIT 2)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e0d6/2)

(As a side note, you may want to add `WHERE category = 'music'` to your second subquery too, since the two parts are totally independent)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SET @level = 0;
SET @group = '';

SELECT 
        id,
        eventid,
        category,
        typ
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        eventid,
        category,
        type,
        @level := IF(@group = type, @level+1, 1) AS level, 
        @group := type as EGroup 
    FROM event_subcategory
    ORDER BY `type`
) rs
WHERE level < 3
```

This will select two records from each group. You can put a where condition inside inner query. With  union you can call like this

```
(SELECT * FROM event_subcategory WHERE `TYPE` = 'event' LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM event_subcategory WHERE `TYPE` = 'page' LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: `TYPE` is [not a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)